# SQL Server 2005 and APP_DATA

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was once told that instead of having to have my host register a SQL Server database file + user/password it is possible instead to put my MDB file into my website's APP_DATA and connect to it directly.  How do I do this?

I tried using the SqlConnection's connection wizard and set
DataSource : Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)
Database file name : Path to a non-existent file in my App_Data folder.
Authentication : (tried both windows and SQL server)

I click OK, at which point I am asked if I wish to create the file or not, I select "Yes".  Then I experience this message:

---

Microsoft Visual Studio

---

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

---

OK

---

I have SQL Server 2005 installed.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you mean .MDF file?

The full path to the filename is in the connection string. Something like:

Server=localhost;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Comment: Yes, MDF :-)

But why is this connection dialog failing with this error?  If I am expecting it to work then surely this dialog should at least succeed in creating the MDB file first?

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, I think what they're talking about is MS SQL Express.